# jQuery function not firing in IE8 within doc.ready

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, document-ready

I am currently browser testing a website I am developing in IE8 and I have defined a global function which is being called both on document ready and window resize. The function seems to be working correctly however within IE8 the function is not firing within the document ready function. It does however fire when the browser is resized.

http://www.montroseclassicfinance.com/testing

I am running IE8 on Win7 within a VM and I cannot figure out why that function isn't firing on document ready or load. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ysp6z/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Call equal height columns function
    pullOutHeight();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    //Call equal height columns function
    pullOutHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    //Call equal height columns function
    pullOutHeight();
});

//Equal height columns function
function pullOutHeight() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        var approachHeight = $('.approach').height() - 15 + 'px';
        $('.pull-out, .col-xs-10').height(approachHeight);
    } else {
        $('.pull-out, .col-xs-10').css('height','auto');
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help,

Lewis.

Comment: Post the relevant code - you're far more likely to get help.

Comment: Sorry, posted the question then realised I hadn't added a Fiddle. Edited now to show the function I am referring to.

Comment: In the fiddle you are running the events from the load event. The ready event has already happened, so jQuery will call the function immediately. The load event won't happen again. For testing you need some elements in the page to see the effect.

Comment: any errors thrown in IE8 console?

Comment: In the fiddle, you aren't even loading jquery (it says no library, pure js). If you change that, then the `ready` event is firing in chrome.

Comment: Sorry I rarely use jsFiddle, I've updated it to include jQuery and have added the CSS & HTML. The function should increase the height of the quote div to match the height of the 'Our Approach' div.

Comment: As mentioned above, the function is working as intended apart from within IE8. Newer versions of IE have no problem firing the function and changing the height of the div.